# Edit button not working properly

Tags: php, cakephp, crud

I am developing a simple application based on `CakePhp` based on database CRUD Operations.
Update(edit) button is not working properly.

**Controller Edit function:**

```
function edit($id = null) {
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (empty($this->data))
        {
            $this->data = $this->User->read();
        }
        else
        {
            if ($this->User->save($this->data))
            {
                $this->flash('Your user with id: '.$id.' has been updated.','/users/read');

                //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'read'));
            }
        }
    }
```

**edit.ctp:**

```
<h1>Edit User</h1>  

<!--?php  
    echo $this--->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'edit'));  
    echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type'=>'hidden'));  
    echo $this->Form->input('first_name');  
    echo $this->Form->input('last_name');  
    echo $this->Form->input('email');  
    echo $this->Form->input('mobile');  
    echo $this->Form->end('Update User');  
?>
```

**uesr.php**

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel
{
var $name='User';
?>
```

here the problem was when i am enter the edit form data will not submitted.

Comment: View the HTML source first. Ensure that the form is being outputted in HTML correctly. You should of course have a `<input type="submit" ... />` which would render a submit button on the form. Post back once you have checked this.

Comment: Also, you could probably elaborate on the error you're receiving. You say the data is not submitted, but is the edit method in the controller ever reached? Try `print_r($_POST);` to dump the POSTed data, if any.

Comment: view will be developing in html but it will store the data in another row.                                                                        <form action="../users/edit" method="POST" name="form">
 UserName:<input type="text" name="username">
          <input type='hidden' name='id' value=" .$users['User']['id']; . ">
 Email:<input type="text" name="email">
 FirstName:<input type="text" name="firstname">
 LastName:<input type="text" name="lastname">
 <input type="submit" value="update User">
 </form>

Comment: If you're writing the view in HTML, then why are you using the CakePHP helpers to generate the form HTML?

Comment: No error message will be display,but data will not be submited edited row.

Comment: i don't know how to use the helpers in cakephp.

Comment: But you already are, in your edit.ctp file. You need to tidy that code up first. You have incorrect syntax:

`<!--?php  
    echo $this--->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'edit'));  `

The opening tag should of course just be `<?php ...`

Comment: ok i modified that tag.still having the same problem

Comment: OK, if the form is being submitted in the browser, time to debug the edit method in the controller. Try print_r($_POST) like I suggested. If that works, ensure $this->data is getting populated and your method executes as you intend.

Comment: that is also not working..

Comment: How is your url looks like? Let know...

Comment: http://localhost/project/UserRegisterForm/users/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I assumed that you already register a user and user $id = 13;

**Edited**
__users_controller.php__

```
function edit($id = null) {

        if (empty($this->data))
        {
            $this->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->User->id = $id;
            if ($this->User->save($this->data))
            {
                $this->flash('Your user with id: '.$id.' has been updated.','/users/read');

                //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'read'));
            }
        }
    }
```

**edit.ctp**

## Edit User

```
<?php  
    echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'edit')); 
    echo $this->Form->input('first_name');  
    echo $this->Form->input('last_name');  
    echo $this->Form->input('email');  
    echo $this->Form->input('mobile');  
    echo $this->Form->end('Update User');  
?>
```

And then try url `localhost/project/UserRegisterForm/users/edit/13`
Here I assumed that you already register a user and user $id = 13;

Comment: I got your problem? Show me your index.ctp

Comment: <h3>New User Form<h3>
 <form action="../users/add" method="POST" name="form">
 UserName:<input type="text" name="username">
 Password:<input type="password" name="password">
 Email:<input type="text" name="email">
 FirstName:<input type="text" name="firstname">
 LastName:<input type="text" name="lastname">
 <input type="submit" value="Save New User">
 </form>

Comment: No no.. not add.ctp.... I'm asking for index.ctp mean from where you are coming to edit.ctp? Ok, update your question with index.ctp

Comment: in my application in index.ctp file empty.not write anything in this file.instead of this i am using my own ctp class(register.ctp)

Comment: I edited my answer. You missed the $id params in your url. Now Register a new user by register.ctp and get the user id from database and put the user id in your url. Better create a index.ctp.

Comment: i am not understand ur answer.please elaborate your answer.

Comment: Do you yet register any user? If yes, look to your user table and tell me one. If no, create a new user.

Comment: when i am add a new user ,user is created and stored in database.

Comment: in my user tableuser id=13

Comment: Now try this url 'localhost/project/UserRegisterForm/users/edit/13'

Comment: Do you getting user information on edit.ctp or its showing blank? I think its blank. Is it?